# How to deal with this exercise using recursion in Python?

Tags: python

I am struggling to solve an exercise regarding lists in Python. The exercise says:

> Write a function that takes a list containing numbers and lists of
> numbers inside them, reverses it (including the lists of numbers
> inside the main list) using recursion.
>
> Afterwards, the function should return a tuple containing three
> elements. The first element represents the amount of all the numbers
> present in the list (including the ones in the sublists), the second
> element is the sum of all the numbers (also the ones inside the
> sublists), and the third element is a sorted list of all the integers.
> Again we should use recursion.

I managed to reverse the whole list using two functions, but when it comes to accessing the numbers inside the sublists to use them for the tuple, I really don't know what to do.

Here you can have a look at the list of lists:

```
lista = [3, 3, 5, [[1, 8, [9, 3]], 3, [2, [9, [5, 6],[9]] ] ]]
```

Here you can check my code:

```
def exercise (lista): 
    lista_ordinata = []
    count = 0
    somma = 0
    reverse_list(lista) 

    for x,y in enumerate(lista):
         if isinstance (x,(int)):
            count += 1
         else:
            count = 0
    for num in lista:
         if isinstance(num,(int)):
            somma += num

    for i in lista:
         if isinstance(i,int):
            lista_ordinata.append(i)
        
    return (count,somma,lista_ordinata)

def is_list (lista):
    return isinstance(lista,list)

def reverse_list(lista):
    lista_nuova = lista[::-1]
    for x,y in enumerate(lista_nuova):
        if is_list(y):
            lista_nuova[x] = reverse_list(y)
    lista.clear()
    lista.extend(lista_nuova)
    return lista
```

Here you can see the expected list which I reversed:

```
lista = [[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]
```

The function must return the following tuple:

```
(13,66, [1,2,3,5,6,8,9])
```

The output I get is incorrect:

```
(4, 11, [5, 3, 3])
```

The first element should be the counting of all the numbers, and not just the numbers outside the sublists, The sum is also incorrect, The list is not outputting all the numbers.

What should I do? Keep in mind that the "exercise" function should use recursion.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the desired result of the exercise is. Reversing the list seems to be irrelevant for the rest of the task.

Comment: Can you please check the indentation of the `exercise` function? The `return` statement seems to be not indented correctly.

Comment: @mkrieger1  The desired result is the tuple, not the list. The list shouldn't be returned, but it has to be reversed, otherwise it won't pass the tests made by teacher.

Comment: @Leo Because i don't know how to do it using recursion

Comment: Ahh ok, did you check to google it? There are a lot of tutorials out there which explain recursion for python.

Comment: @Leo Yes, i did. Is there any specific tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: Hi! I think you used recursion quite ok in the reverse list function, just a bit of implementation issue on the second part, I will try to post a solution :)

Comment: You should reverse the list using recursion right? So you cannot do `my_list[::-1]`, if I understand correctly. What I don't understand is, how is this thing even related? Instead of reversing the list, we can directly sort it.

Comment: And you need separate function for sum/count/expansion

Comment: If you understand how to reverse the list without resorting to [::-1], then the other two should be trivial. All three can be done at the same time, in a single recursive function.

Comment: check my solution with indirect recursion, with a 2 line solution to part 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
def exercise(a, polish=sorted):
  if not isinstance(a, list):
    return 1, a, {a}
  a.reverse()
  amount, sum, numbers = 0, 0, set()
  for b in a:
    a, s, n = exercise(b, set)
    amount += a
    sum += s
    numbers |= n
  return amount, sum, polish(numbers)
```

Or with a little helper doing the reversals and collecting the numbers:

```
def exercise(a):
  def go(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
      a.reverse()
      for b in a:
        go(b)
    else:
      numbers.append(a)
  numbers = []
  go(a)
  return len(numbers), sum(numbers), sorted(set(numbers))
```

Demo:

```
lista = [3, 3, 5, [[1, 8, [9, 3]], 3, [2, [9, [5, 6],[9]] ] ]]

>>> exercise(lista)
(13, 66, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])

>>> lista
[[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using recursion just fine in the `reverse` function, just use recursion in you `exercise` function:

```
def exercise(lista): 
    lista_ordinata = []
    count = 0
    somma = 0
    # reverse_list(lista)
    
    for x in lista:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            recursion = exercise(x) # call recursion until you have a list with only integers
            # and add the result to your running totals
            count += recursion[0]
            somma += recursion[1]
            lista_ordinata.extend(recursion[2])
        else:
            count += 1
            somma += x
            lista_ordinata.append(x)
    
    lista_ordinata = sorted(list(set(lista_ordinata)))
    
    return count, somma, lista_ordinata

print(exercise(lista))

(13, 66, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way without any loops at all.

First of all, we can have a definition for a partial insertion sort, which inserts any value to its correct position in an existing sorted array.

```
def partialInsertionSort(val, idx, sortarr):
    if idx == len(sortarr):
        sortarr.append(val)
    elif val < sortarr[idx]:
        sortarr.insert(idx, val)
    elif val > sortarr[idx]:
        sortarr = partialInsertionSort(val, idx+1, sortarr)

    return sortarr
```

As you travel through any list `a`, unless you've reached the end of `a`, there are two possibilities:

- The current item is another list -> Recurse through the sublist!
- The current item is a digit -> Increment total and count. If this digit is a previously unseen digit, 'insert' it to your list of sorted digits.

Done with the above two possible options, you have thus processed the current element, and can move to the next element by incrementing the index i.

```
def reverse_and_sort(a, i, out, sortarr, total, count):
    if i==len(a): 
        return out, sortarr, total, count

    if isinstance(a[i], list):
        a[i], sortarr, total, count = reverse_and_sort(a[i], 0, [], sortarr, total, count)
    else:
        total += a[i]
        count += 1
        if a[i] not in sortarr:
            sortarr = partialInsertionSort(a[i], 0, sortarr)

    out.insert(0, a[i])
    return reverse_and_sort(a, i+1, out, sortarr, total, count)
```

Test:

```
rev, srt, total, count = reverse_and_sort(lista, 0, [], [], 0, 0)
print(rev)    #[[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]
print(srt)    #[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
print(total)  #66
print(count)  #13
```

Answer (score 1):

A relatively short version, which uses the `add` operator is given by that:

```
from operator import add

def sorter(l):
    if isinstance(l, list):
        temp = [0, 0, []]
        for e in map(sorter, l):
            temp = list(map(add, e, temp))
        return temp[0], temp[1], sorted(set(temp[2]))
    return 1, l, [l]
```

It should give the correct result:

```
test_list = [[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]
sorter(test_list)

>>> (13, 66, [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Two liner approach!**

Here is a simple solution to the problem, using indirect recursion. Indirect recursion is where a function f(x) calls a function g(x) which in turn calls f(x).

[image]

If your problem was just the first part, the solution is just a simple 2 liner -

```
f = lambda x: [g(i) for i in reversed(x)]
g = lambda x: f(x) if type(x)==list else x

f(lista)
```

```
[[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]
```

Beautiful right?

The main idea here is that at an element level you just need to check if the element is an integer and return it, else you need to use another function that lets you iterate over the list. You can have counters at the level of the second function which lets you track the sum and the count and return it with the final function call.

---

Since you also have the 2nd part to the solution which is using a few counters, you can modify the above code for g(x) to incorporate that as below -

```
cnt = []
sm = []

#function to iterate over a reversed list
f = lambda x: [g(i) for i in reversed(x)]

#function to call f if list else updated counters and return element
def g(x):
    if type(x)==list:
        return f(x)
    else: 
        cnt.append(1)  #ONLY MODIFICATION
        sm.append(x)   #ONLY MODIFICATION    
        return x
    
#call f and return sum of counters
def rec(l):
    o = f(l)
    return o, (sum(cnt), sum(sm), sorted(sm))


out, tup = rec(lista)

print(out)
print(tup)
```

```
[[[[[9], [6, 5], 9], 2], 3, [[3, 9], 8, 1]], 5, 3, 3]

(13, 66, [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def exercise(lista, total = 0, count = 0, all_int = []):
  for item in lista:
    if isinstance(item, list):
      count, total, all_int = exercise(item, total, count, all_int)
    elif isinstance(item, int):
      total += item
      count += 1
      if item not in all_int:
        all_int.append(item)
        all_int.sort()
  lista.reverse()
  return count, total, all_int
```

Maybe this would help :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
def exercise (lista):
    reverse_list(lista)
    r = count_numbers(lista), sum_numbers(lista), sorted(pull_out(lista))
    return r



def is_list (lista):
    return isinstance(lista,list)

def reverse_list(lista):
    lista_nuova = []
    for e in lista[::-1]:
        if is_list(e):
            lista_nuova.append(reverse_list(e))
        else:
            lista_nuova.append(e)
    return lista_nuova


def count_numbers(lista):
    c = 0
    for e in lista:
        if is_list(e):
            c += count_numbers(e)
        else:
            c+=1
    return c

def sum_numbers(lista):
    s = 0
    for e in lista:
        if is_list(e):
            s += sum_numbers(e)
        else:
            s+=e
    return s

def pull_out(lista):
    b_lista = []
    for e in lista:
        if is_list(e):
            b_lista.extend(pull_out(e))
        else:
            b_lista.append(e)
    return b_lista


lista = [3, 3, 5, [[1, 8, [9, 3]], 3, [2, [9, [5, 6],[9]] ] ]]
r = exercise(lista)
print(r)
# (13, 66, [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9])
```

I did it with separate functions for clarity.